# Deploying Crystal Reports for Visual Studio on Windows 7 64 bit systems via Clickonce

Tags: visual-studio-2012, deployment, crystal-reports

I have written an application that uses CR for Visual Studio. It deploys and runs fine on 32 bit systems. I want it to work on 64 bit systems too, so I ran `CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_7.msi` to install the redistributable.

When I select my prerequisites in VS 2012, should I see an entry for CR 64 bit? I don't.

In VS, I set the target CPU to x64 and publish (Clickonce). When I try to install it on my Win 7 64 bit system, I get an error:

`Unable to install or run the application. The application requires that assembly CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonObjectMode Version 13.0.2000.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first.`

How can I deploy the 64 bit CR runtime with my application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a bug with the Service Pack 7 version of the files?  Have you tried with the Service Pack 8 version that was recently released?

[SAP Crystal Reports, Developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)

Is your development environment 32-bit or 64-bit?  Because that might have a bit to do with it also.  Installing and deploying Crystal has always been a pain (I've been working with it since version 7.0) and to introduce the complexity of 32/64-bit makes it even more fun!

Another thing to point out on that link was that you have to run the "Install executable" to get it to integrate into VS properly.  When I did so, it asked me if I wanted to install the 64-bit runtime as my PC was 64-bit, did you get to this point and if so, which version did you choose?

In the app we're working on, we have a routine that inspects all assemblies in the dependencies folder and auto-loads classes with a certain attribute, but when I went to run the app targeting a 64-bit CPU (or even Any CPU) it would give me exceptions when trying to load the Crystal Reports assemblies on start-up, but it would work fine when targeting a 32-bit CPU.

Which leads me to think that perhaps they either don't have their 32/64-bitness sorted properly, or their installer isn't doing what it says it is.

Comment: I was working working with service pack 8. My development environment is 64 bit. I ran the executable and got it to integrate with VS with no problems. It asked if I wanted to install the 64 bit runtime, and I said yes. The only thing I can my program to install on is a 32 bit system. I have pretty much given up on Crystal Reports.

Comment: In other news, I hear MS have got the bit-ness sorted on SQL Server Reporting Services first go.  ;-)